# If i forgot to fill field than not show laravel error

Tags: laravel, postman, postmortem-debugging, postman-testcase

This is my code of register controller...I applied code through try catch but in postman still show error like this

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse::__construct() must be of the type integer, string given, called in /home/ynvih0l26evc/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php on line 31 in file /home/ynvih0l26evc/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/JsonResponse.php on line 42
```

```html
public function register(Request $request) {  
     try {
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
              [ 
              'user_type' => 'required',
              'fname' => 'required',
              'lname' => 'required',
              'dob' => 'required',
              'phone' => 'required',
              'gender' => 'required',
              'uname' => 'required',
              'email' => 'required|email',
              'password' => 'required',  
              'c_password' => 'required|same:password', 
             ]);   

$input = $request->all();  
 $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
 $user = User::create($input); 
 $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
 $success['status'] = true;
 $success['data'] = [$user];
 $success['message'] ="User created successfully!";  
  return response()->json($success, $this->successStatus); 

 } catch(\Throwable $e) {
            // For php7
            \Log::error($e->getFile().' '.$e->getLine().': '.$e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(1000, 'Error');
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            // For php5
            \Log::error($e->getFile().' '.$e->getLine().': '.$e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(1000, 'Error');
        }

}
```

In API i forgot to fill field still record submit and not show laravel error an response success or failure show in json format. How can i do that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function register(Request $request) {  
 $input = $request->all();
 $rules = array(
            'user_type' => 'required',
              'fname' => 'required',
              'lname' => 'required',
              'dob' => 'required',
              'phone' => 'required',
              'gender' => 'required',
              'uname' => 'required',
              'email' => 'required|email',
              'password' => 'required',  
              'c_password' => 'required|same:password', 
        );
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
if ($validator->fails()) {
         $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => $validator->errors()->first(), "data" => array());
} else {
try {

 $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
 $user = User::create($input); 
 $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
 $success['status'] = true;
 $success['data'] = [$user];
 $success['message'] ="User created successfully!";  
  return response()->json($success, $this->successStatus); 

 } catch(\Throwable $e) {
            // For php7
            \Log::error($e->getFile().' '.$e->getLine().': '.$e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(1000, 'Error');
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            // For php5
            \Log::error($e->getFile().' '.$e->getLine().': '.$e->getMessage());
            return response()->json(1000, 'Error');
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I try this code but in postman show output nothing -@Vikas Katariya

Comment: data is insert in database?